# How can I add something on the top right of each slide of Beamer (Warsaw theme)

Tags: beamer, positioning, presentations

I have the following code of beamer presentation with warsaw theme, I added a logo in the right top, and i would like to add the institute and the subject in the same area, any help?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
    \usetheme{Warsaw}

    \makeatletter
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}
    {%
      \leavevmode%
      \@tempdimb=2.4375ex%
      \ifnum\beamer@subsectionmax<\beamer@sectionmax%
        \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%
      \else%
        \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@subsectionmax%
      \fi%
      \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
        \advance\@tempdimb by 1.825ex%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
          \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{subsection in head/foot}%
          \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsubsectionnavigation{.3\paperwidth}\vfil}%
          \hfill
          \includegraphics[height=\headheight]{example-image}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
      \fi%
    }
    \makeatother

    \begin{document}

    \section{bla}
    \begin{frame}
    contenants
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \@tempdimb=2.4375ex%
  \ifnum\beamer@subsectionmax<\beamer@sectionmax%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%
  \else%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@subsectionmax%
  \fi%
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
    \advance\@tempdimb by 1.825ex%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \quad
      \yoursubject
      \hfill
      \insertshortinstitute        
      \hfill
      \raisebox{-0.65em}{\includegraphics[height=\headheight]{example-image}}
      \vfill
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\subject}[1]{%
  \hypersetup{pdfsubject={#1}}%
  \newcommand{\yoursubject}{#1}
}

\title{title}
\institute{institute}
\subject{Your subject}

\begin{document}

\section{bla}
\begin{frame}
contenants
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, the subject is well defined in warsaw theme unfortunately this is not working with me

Comment: @Fog_convergence Please have a look now

Comment: Thank you very much for your time but it still not working

Comment: @Fog_convergence "Not working" is not a very informative feedback.

Comment: I am sorry, there is no errors but also there is nothing in that way ( top right)

Comment: @Fog_convergence Did you try with the very same code from my answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74515/discussion-between-fog-convergence-and-samcarter).